# Filtering results from textbox to DataGridView

Tags: c#, search, datagridview, filtering

I want to filter/search some results from my existing DataGridView Table. I have done most of them except one field. That's the first field of my DataGridView Table "Product ID" it's an Int data type field. So I think it needs a bit conversion on the Int Value to System.String.. but I'm not getting how to fix that.. Can any one please help me..

```
private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try 
        {
            DataView DV = new DataView(dbdataset);
            DV.RowFilter = string.Format("Convert[Product ID,'System.String'] LIKE '%{0}%' OR [Product Name] LIKE '%{0}%' OR [Brand Name] LIKE '%{0}%' OR [Pro. Size ID] LIKE '%{0}%'", Convert.ToString(txtSearch.Text));
            dgView.DataSource = DV;
        }
         catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Error_txt.Text = ex.Message;
        }

    }
```

It gives an error

`Syntax error: Missing operand after '[Product ID,'System.String()']' operator.`

Answer (score 1):

Finally I figure it out. Now I can filter both Integer and String inputs.

```
DV.RowFilter = string.Format("Convert([Product ID], System.String) LIKE '%{0}%' OR [Product Name] LIKE '%{0}%' OR [Brand Name] LIKE '%{0}%' OR [Pro. Size ID] LIKE '%{0}%'", txtSearch.Text);
```